# How to make scrollable to jPanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am making swing application. And there is too much height of my jPanel. So I want to make this panel as scrollable.:
Following is my description of my requirement.

I have four jpanel in one jpanel I mean:

```
JPanel p1=new JPanel();
JPanel p2=new JPanel();
JPanel p3=new JPanel();
JPanel p4=new JPanel();
```

I am adding `p2, p3, p4` inside `p1` like following output:

[image: MyOutput]

like above showing panel has more height than computer screen height. So I want to display all content of my panel on computer screen by scrolling.

I searched here and found the following questions:

- [How to make a JPanel scrollable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201990/how-to-make-a-jpanel-scrollable)
- [How do i get vertical scrolling to JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287761/how-do-i-get-vertical-scrolling-to-jpanel)

However, the answers did not solve myproblem.

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for better help soooner.

Comment: I had designed this using swing GUI editor from netbeans IDE.

Comment: *"I had designed this using swing GUI editor from netbeans IDE."*  Swap out all that rubbish for an image of size 200,900, display the image in a label, put the label in a panel, and you are close to having an SSCCE where the code is 'Short' as in the first word of SSCCE.  No one wants (or asked for) another 'Netbeans GUI editor code dump'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing your code, my guess is that you don't have a `JScrollpane` to provide the scrollable behaviour you want.

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(); //This would be the base panel of your UI
JPanel p1=new JPanel();
JPanel p2=new JPanel();
JPanel p3=new JPanel();
JPanel p4=new JPanel();
JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
newPanel.add(p1);
newPanel.add(p2);
newPanel.add(p3);
newPanel.add(p4);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(newPanel);
mainPanel.add(pane);
```

Since you use NetBeans, add a `JScrollpane` from the palette in which you'll add a panel to contain the 4 others. I think you could also just add the 4 panel into the `JScrollpane`.

Answer (score 3):

Add your panel to a `JScrollPane`. Assumed that you want vertical scrolling only:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(panel, 
   ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,  
   ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

For fine-tuning the scroll amounts, you can optionally implement the `Scrollable` interface.
See also [How to Use Scroll Panes (The Java Tutorial)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to design scroll pane using Netbeans IDE. Below given are the steps I followed to add a scroll pane:

```
    1. In Netbeans GUI editor, select all panels which requires scroll pane using CTRL+left click
    2. Right click on the hilighted panels, select the option 'Enclose in' -> Scroll Pane. This will add a scroll pane for the selected panels.
    3. If there are other elements than Panel(say JTree), select all the elements ->Enclose in ->Panel. Then enlose the new parent panel to scroll pane
    4. Make sure that 'Auto Resizing' is turned on for the selected parent panel(Right click on panel -> Auto resizing -> Tick both Horizontal and vertical)
```