# Scroll content of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I went to multiple articles about this problem but i can't fix it.
According to this article: [How to make scrollable to jPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408668/how-to-make-scrollable-to-jpanel)
i made this:

```
    nieuw.add(onder, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(nieuw);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(300,300,300,300);
    hoofd.add(scrollPane);
    add(hoofd);
```

`onder` contains the content, so i added a JScrollPane to it, but the scrollbar doesn't appear (see image).

[image: packet]

I hope you guys know the answer, thank you in advance!!

Comment: The code you posted doesn't tell us anything about your applicaton so all we can do is guess:  1) Don't use null layouts!!! 2) Don't use setPreferredSize()!!! 3) All of your panels need to use layout managers if you want scrolling to work properly. 4) Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem if you need more help because we can't spend time guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixt it with `scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(580,320));`
so my final code:

```
JPanel hoofd = new JPanel();
JPanel onder = new JPanel();
JPanel nieuw = new JPanel(); 
nieuw.add(onder, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(nieuw);

scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(580,320));
scrollPane.setBounds(300,300,300,300);

hoofd.add(scrollPane);
add(hoofd);
```